# Reduce $SU(3)$ fundamental representation into irreps of $SU(2)$ subalgebra

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

I'm working on problems in Georgi's book on Lie algebras and can't figure out what I'm supposed to do on this problem (7B):

Show that $T_1$, $T_2$, and $T_3$ generate an $SU(2)$ subalgebra of $SU(3)$. Every representation of $SU(3)$ must also be a representation of the subalgebra. However, the irreducible representations of $SU(3)$ are not necessarily irreducible under the subalgebra. How does the representation generated by the Gell-Mann matrices transform under this subalgebra? That is, reduce, if necessary, the three dimensional representation into representations which are irreducible under the subalgebra and state which irreducible representations appear in the reduction. Then answer the same question for the adjoint representation of $SU(3)$.

It's clear to me why there are $SU(2)$ subalgebras of $SU(3)$, and I suppose if you will answer this you also know that without me explicitly writing the $T_a$s. What I don't understand is what he means by "transforming under the subalgebra," nor can I find an explanation online. What does "irreducible under the subalgebra" mean?

Comment: You know $[\lambda_{1,2,3}, \lambda_8]=0$. So this SU(2) acting on the upper 2-components of a 3-vector amounts to a **2** , but acting on the 3rd component does nothing. So the **3** of SU(3) reduces to a **2** and a singlet **1** of SU(2). Now consider the adjoint, etc..

Comment: After getting further through the book I've come back to questions I'm unsure of, and I still don't know how to do this one. I now understand the 3 = 2+1 that you've described here, but I don't know how to do the adjoint representation. My professor said we can do 8+1 = 3x3 and then decompose the 3x3 = (2+1) x (2+1) = 3+2+2+1+1 under SU(2), but how does 3* transform if we know how 3 transforms (since it's 8+1=3x3*)?

Comment: Also, this far into the book he hasn't described the 3* representation, so I figure there should be a way other than what I describe above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A triplet **v** transforming under SU(3) means 
$$
\mathbf {v} \mapsto \exp (i\theta^a \lambda_a)~~ \mathbf {v}.
$$
So you see the third component of this complex 3-vector is left alone under action of the SU(2) subgroup (has been reduced out), generated by the SU(2) subalgebra $\{\lambda_1\equiv T_1,\lambda_2\equiv T_2,\lambda_3\equiv T_3\}$.  That is, for $\theta^a=(a,b,c,0,0,0,0,0)\equiv\vec\phi$, a 3-vector parameter, 
$$
\mathbf {v} \mapsto \exp (i\vec\phi \cdot \vec T)~~ \mathbf {v}.
$$
The upper two components, though, transform into each other, so they are irreducible under this restricted, SU(2) subgroup transformation.
So **v** is really a ***2***  ⊕ ***1*** , the singlet being the 3rd component.

Now the 8-vectors $ W^a {\mathbf v}^\dagger \lambda^a {\mathbf v} $ transform in the adjoint of SU(3), 
$$
 W^a {\mathbf v}^\dagger \lambda^a {\mathbf v} \mapsto  W^a {\mathbf v}^\dagger \!\exp (-i\theta^c \lambda_c)~~ \lambda^a \exp (i\theta^b \lambda_b){\mathbf v},
$$
so you see how the ***3*** * transforms: by the hermitian conjugate generators.

So, again, if you restrict the 8 *λ*s to the three *T*s of the SU(2) subalgebra, 
the adjoint octet transforms under SU(2) as
$$
 W^a {\mathbf v}^\dagger \lambda^a {\mathbf v} \mapsto  W^a {\mathbf v}^\dagger \!\exp (-i\vec\phi\cdot \vec T)~~ \lambda^a \exp (i\vec\phi\cdot \vec T){\mathbf v}.
$$

Now, consider the transformations among the 8 components of $W^a$.
Again, you see that the upper 3 components of $W^a$, corresponding to the subalgebra of the *T*s , are mixed into each other by the SU(2) subalgebra, and so are an irreducible triplet. The eighth component, corresponds to $\lambda_8$, which commutes with the *T*s, so it is a singlet under SU(2).

The other four components split into two conjugate SU(2) doublets,($\lambda_4 +i\lambda_5, \lambda_6+i\lambda_7$), and the $i\to -i$ combination, ("the *K* and $\bar K$" of the meson octet)  as you may observe by the transformation properties of $\{ \lambda_4,\lambda_5,\lambda_6,\lambda_7  \}$ under the SU(2)--their commutators with the *T*s.  The other singlet of the nonet reduction your teacher wrote is ${\mathbf v}^\dagger {\mathbf v}$ which is also a singlet under SU(3), so it never entered the discussion to start with.

Comment: This was very helpful for understanding the general idea. It's not obvious just from looking at it, but I assume if I throw the last expression into Mathematica I'll see all the n-tuplets. The only thing I'm confused with is why we look at how the object $W^a v^\dag \lambda^a v$ transforms, instead of some other 8-vector? I feel I'm missing something crucial here - I'm not taking this as a class, just straight reading from the text, so it's difficult to gauge my understanding.

Comment: Sorry to resort to physics, but the [meson octet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meson) made out of quark (flavor) triplets illustrates the ${\mathbf 3}^* \otimes {\mathbf 3} = {\mathbf 8}\oplus{\mathbf 1}$ involved... You could discuss any and all octets, but looking at a concrete realization makes the accounting hands on and tangible... The SU(2) subgroup is the horizontal lines of constant strangeness *S* on the "stop sign" diagram... You see the pion triplet, K doublets, and eta singlet....

Comment: @CosmasZachos Do you know if there is a general, "accepted" name of this topic, i.e. induced subalgebra/subgroup representations? I've seen this idea pop up many times in the context of SSB of global symmetries in QFT.

Comment: No idea... Slansky’s classic review calls it reduction under subalgebra, no?